# How to get metrics from my Linux VM in Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I'm trying to get computer metrics like RAM, Left space, cpu usage and etc, but this ins't working.
I'm using so RH 7.5 and the agent is installed, also my vm is recognized in azure portal.

Others VMs are working fine.

P.S. I'd already install Agent to pick this metrics and logs.

Comment: You can take a look at the vm extension if it shows the state as the success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing the agent you have to enable the diagnostics extension to get OS level metrics.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management/azure-vm-extended-metrics